# Adding a timetable scheduling after after user has logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working on my final year project which is to create a web application using asp.net MVC C#. The aim of this project is allow nurses (users)  to view their timetables once they have logged in. I have already created the database which contains all my data and i also finish the login system which works. However i am having trouble with displaying the timetable which applies for each nurse when they have logged in.

I am looking for opinions and advice to help me with this issue. will be much appreciate it.

Comment: we are having trouble while trying to help people that doesn't share even 1 line of code and asking for a solution....

Answer (score 0):

Once the user logs in, you should be able to get his ID.
If you use Identity, that would be User.Identity.GetUserId(), if you use something custom, I'm sure you still have some sort of ID that identifies currently logged user. This ID, either directly or indirectly, should let you fetch timetable records for that user using whatever data access layer you got there. You put these records into your View Model, and then in your View iterate over these records to present them any way you want, probably a table of some kind.

Comment: thank you for your advise, i am having trouble with creating the timetable system but once this is done , i will go ahead with everything you mention. by the way have you got any experience on how to build a timetable schedule?